# ReactJS: "Error: React.createElement is not a function"

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs, jsx

I have been using React for a while now, and my version was horribly out of date. I updated to 0.12 without incident. Then I tried upgrading react tools as well. That is when everything broke. Now I am getting the following error: "Error: React.createElement is not a function". Other than a vague idea that this probably has something to do with the changes to the JSX transformer, I have no idea why upgrading react tools is leading to this error. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without a code sample, but probably you are not requiring react in your component file? that is a standard javascript error, nothing to do with JSX

Comment: Why would this have changed with the upgrade? Everything runs fine with the old version of react tools

Comment: can you post the code sample for the component that causes the error?

Comment: It's not a specific component, it happens when I try to load the project at all

Comment: Following the stacktrace, you should be able to find out the component / file for which you get this error

Comment: It's the parent component. When it tries to create the component, the JSX transformer has replaced my `<MyComponent` syntax with `React.createElement` which I know is new in the recent release. My question is, if I have upgraded React, why does this function not exist

Comment: Not sure what to say, but maybe you can check the changelog doc: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0122-december-18-2014, there's something there for `createElement`

Answer (score -1):

This same class of problem can happen in other ways, so i will link to the other issue, rather than duplicating the same answer here. Not sure if there's a more 'standard' way to link two posts.

[ReactJS: React.render is not a function and React.createElement is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166125/reactjs-react-render-is-not-a-function-and-react-createelement-is-not-a-functio)