# ReactJS: React.render is not a function and React.createElement is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found a problem in my code when I was trying to use these two functions in my React version 15.2.0, nonetheless, I found a workaround but I would like to know if there's a better solution.

```
//app.jsx
var React = require('react');

var ThumbnailList = require('./thumbnail-list');

var options = {
     ThumbNailData: [{
     title : 'Download the ISO',
     number : 32,
     header : 'Learning React',
     description: 'The best library for creating fast and dynamic websites.',
     imageUrl : 'image source'
    },{
     title : 'Download the ISO',
     number : 64,
     header : 'Learning Gulp',
     description: 'Speed your development framework!',
     imageUrl : 'image source'
    }],
};

var element = React.createElement(ThumbnailList,options);
React.render(element, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

So, whenever I try to run my index.html file nothing is displayed but this first error comes into the console: **React.render is not a function**. I found that this occurs because this new version of React needs the react-dom, that is,

```
//app.jsx
var React = require('react-dom');

var ThumbnailList = require('./thumbnail-list');

var options = {
     ThumbNailData: [{
     title : 'Download the ISO',
     number : 32,
     header : 'Learning React',
     description: 'The best library for creating fast and dynamic websites.',
     imageUrl : 'image source'
    },{
     title : 'Download the ISO',
     number : 64,
     header : 'Learning Gulp',
     description: 'Speed your development framework!',
     imageUrl : 'image source'
    }],
};

var element = React.createElement(ThumbnailList,options);
React.render(element, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Now the problem is solved but now comes the second problem when you try to run again the index.html: **React.CreateElement is not a function.** What I did was to add another variable requiring react, that is,

```
var React = require('react-dom');
var React2 = require('react');
var ThumbnailList = require('./thumbnail-list');

var options = {
    ThumbNailData: [{
        title : 'Download the ISO',
        number : 32,
        header : 'Learning React',
        description: 'The best library for creating fast and dynamic  websites.',
        imageUrl : 'image-source'
    },{
        title : 'Download the ISO',
        number : 64,
        header : 'Learning Gulp',
        description: 'Speed your development framework!',
        imageUrl : 'image-source'
   }],
};

var element = React2.createElement(ThumbnailList,options);
React.render(element, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

In few words, to solve the problem of React.render

```
var React = require('react-dom')
```

to solve the problem of React.createElement

```
var React2 = require('react')
```

My questions are:

1. Why the react-dom created the problem with React.createElement?
2. Is it because of this new version of React?
3. Is there a better approach to solve these problems without having to invoke react-dom and react?

Any thoughts and comments are appreciated ;)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First of all, since React v0.14, there is this new package called `react-dom`. It abstracts the "environment" that you will run React, and, in your case, is the browser.

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#two-packages-react-and-react-dom

So, since you have now two packages: "`react`" to create your React components and "`react-dom`" to "integrate" React with the browser, you need to call the correct methods that each one of them provides.

Then, answering your questions:

> Why the react-dom created the problem with React.createElement?

The package that has `React.createElement` is `react` and **not** `react-dom`.

> Is it because of this new version of React?

Yes, you are not able to call `React.render` (from package `react`) anymore, you need to use `ReactDOM.render` (from package `react-dom`).

> Is there a better approach to solve these problems without having to invoke react-dom and react?

I don't see it as a "problem", you just need to know that now there is a specific package to manipulate DOM. Also, it is a "good" pattern, because if sometime you want to render your components as an HTML (to render it using a server), you just need to adapt some things and your code will be the same.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting error: "React.createElement is not a function" and for my situation the fix was to change this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

TO THIS:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

This was in a TypeScript file so i'm not sure it applies to non-TypeScript or not.

Comment: I had a similar error/fix. I had

import React, { Text, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";

and changed it to

import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";

Answer (score -2):

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World!</h1>, document.getElementID("root"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. When adding an answer to a four year olde question with an accepted answer it is important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.