# Error provides .render not a function in ReactJS. App.js is not running properly on LocalHost

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code in index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react";

import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The code in App.js

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>App</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

I'm currently following a Youtube Tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khJlrj3Y6Ls

As you will notice at 7:45, the video creator has the same code as I do, however, for some reason his app works when running it but mines doesn't. I'm new to React and have understanding of the main concepts by working through this document https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html . I would love your help on identifying why my app is not working and when running it on my localhost, I get the following message:

```
TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.render is not a function
Module../src/index.js
src/index.js:6
  3 | 
  4 | import App from "./App";
  5 | 
> 6 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Depends how old the video is. [This might be the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38166183/1377002). Try changing the package to `react-dom` after you're sure it's installed.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code as such, so you need to look at the webpack/build process. Something is amiss there, but it's impossible to say what.

Comment: Hi Andy, THANK YOU! Yes, it works now!! I needed to: import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

Answer (score 0):

if you had the same question: the problem, as Andy pointed out, was that you will need to:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

previously, ReactDOM was being imported from react.

This lists more of the details; [ReactJS: React.render is not a function and React.createElement is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166125/reactjs-react-render-is-not-a-function-and-react-createelement-is-not-a-functio/38166183#38166183)